# Box2D SetGravityScale does not work when I set it back to 1

Tags: c++, box2d

I have a jumping game. There are some items that when the jumper collects then it stays in the air for 3 seconds and then falls down. For that I have done the following:

```
// to stop the body in the air
body->SetGravityScale(0);
body->SetLinearDamping(7); // don't want abrupt stopping
```

To make body to fall again from the air back to the ground after 3 seconds I do:

```
body->SetGravityScale(1);                
body->SetLinearDamping(0);
```

But it continues to stay in the air. Only when I apply a small impulse towards down it starts to fall. Why?

EDIT: I have explicitly set:

```
m_world.SetAllowSleeping(false);
```

but anyways, I should apply linear impulse to make him fall back or simply do:

```
body->SetAwake(true);
```

It turns that body is sleeping even if `m_world.SetAllowSleeping(false);`. Is this OK?

Comment: First thing I would do is look at the debug draw display, then you can tell us whether the body is actually sleeping or not.

Comment: When I commented the line containing `m_world.SetAllowSleeping(false);` on debug draw it really slept when I set `body->SetGravityScale(0);`. I have explicitly set `m_world.SetAllowSleeping(false);` and it worked without `body->SetAwake(true);`. Seems something when wrong with compilation and it did not update the executable.

Answer (score 0):

Check your world and see if it have gravity, even with gravityScale = 1 your body won't fall without gravity in the world.

If your problem is not there, check if your body can be affected by gravity checking if the body is a dynamic body.

I think it would be best if I commented it in your question, but I don't have enough Rep for that :/

Hope it helps :)

Comment: No it does not help at all, cause if you were attentive while reading my question you would understand that I have gravity setup and body is dynamic too. The only problem is body is sleeping when I turn off the gravity for it.